# how to hide image on page load and then show like sliding after some time

Tags: javascript, html

I have web page i want that when page is loaded after some time it slide images without any click I am using following code it slides on button click but also shows images when page loaded but i want to slide after some time when page is loaded and initially images should be hidden

below is the demo link which is done

http://jsfiddle.net/WM5tA/2/

Comment: can you explain me more how to do this

Comment: this way: http://jsfiddle.net/WM5tA/3/

Comment: yes like this but it hides i want to show like this after some time not from bottom to up slide but from right to left and then image shoudl show on actual div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract your function and call it in a setTimeout and also in your click handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/WM5tA/4/

**Js**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(slideAround, 5000); // Toggles the slide after 5 seconds      
        $("input[type=button]").click(slideAround);
        });

 function slideAround() {
        $(".imageone, .imagetwo").slideToggle();
   }
```

**Update**

To show the divs when in a Timeout rather than hiding them simply set the elements to display:none; in your CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/WM5tA/6/

**CSS**

```
.imageone, .imagetwo
            {
                [...]
                display:none;
            }
```

**Update 2**

To slide your elements from right to left you'll need to use jQuery UI like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WM5tA/7/

```
$(".imageone, .imagetwo").show("slide",{direction: "right"}, 1000);
```

Comment: i just want to slide for one time and then it show the image and there should be no button for click event

Comment: If you also use jQuery UI then yes. See here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Comment: @Can you help me please that can be done slide from right to left or not

Comment: how to do that in our code all thing is correct but it should slide from right to left please if you can help

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript for the document ready function, set a timeout (in milliseconds) calling your slide code for how long after the page has loaded you want to wait before calling your function to slide. For example waiting one second:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $(".imageone, .imagetwo").slideToggle(); },1000);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vdgDB/1/

Comment: Its doing that initially it shows images then after some it slides and images are not visible i want that images should slide from left to right and then visible